# Is there anyway to write android applications in PHP?

Tags: php, android

Is there anyway to write android applications in PHP?

This page clearly mentions that Android apps should be written in Java. Just wondering if there is another way...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: Yes it is. http://phpforandroid.net

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. However, if you're so inclined, you could make a web app that checks for the Android browser and only displays on the Andriod. That would make an internet connection required though.

I haven't used the Android myself, but maybe it has Gears support like Chrome does. If so, then you can integrate Gears into the app and have them download it onto their Android.

Comment: Well then you can absolutely code an app for Android, as long as you make your app gears-compatible.. Whatever code you let Gears download will run without a connection on the Android, and then if you need to sync with an online service when you connect, you can do that as well.

Comment: what is Gears? any example of it?

Comment: @JackTurky Google has actually discontinued Gears, but standard modern browser technologies are now sufficient for running apps in the browser.

Your target technology will depend on what you're building, but hardware accelerated 3D graphics through Canvas/WebGL, animations via hardware-accelerated CSS3, and many more, will help you achieve acceptable performance.

Of course, native apps are usually preferred if hardware acceleration and tight system integration is important.

Answer (score 2):

PHP for android works just fine, just remember you need to install ASE (Android Scripting Environment) first and then PFA and plugins. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken Google has built a special framework for Andriod, it uses java syntax and you can import java libraries to it.

But as BraedenP said you can still check for android browser and render a special page for andriod, yet you won't have access to the it's resources(hardware).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java is the preferred way, but there are other ways as well:

- Visual Basic-like language, called [Simple](http://code.google.com/p/simple/).
- [C/C++](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-15-ndk-release-1.html)
- [C# via Mono](http://code.google.com/p/androidmono/) - this one is still in development.

Comment: Would Quercus run under Android?  It's a PHP runtime written in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write applications in PHP .But at the end , they will be webapp only and not be able to provide some behaviour/functionality  as provided by Native applications developed in Java /C++

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need PHP. If you example need something from a database, then you can connect trough jquery ajax. From the server yuo will send a json object with the query/data you wan't. ofcourse you can do this to download files from the server if you wan't to create a update system to. Thats how i make my applications. Im sorry for my english, i hope you understand :)