# Android and php

Tags: php, android

there is any possible to implement php applications in android phone without using the web browser.if there then help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Is there anyway to write android applications in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415483/is-there-anyway-to-write-android-applications-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, but you can create a webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain yourself what do u mean exactly!
Android having a browser can act as client do u mean can we use android as server?
I think that will be restricted by the software itself mean web server and php executables and then the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: http://phpforandroid.net