# Is there any way to build android source code from php?

Tags: php, android, linux, sdk

I need to build android source code into .apk file using php , is that some thing i can do ?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: To create the APK, you'll need Java. Only thing you can realize in PHP is the API for your app (which provides the data).

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/1415483/1021695

Comment: You want to build java source code into an apk, using a system developed in java, is that right? or you want to build php code into an android apk?

Comment: @DallaRosa Yes i want to build java source code into an apk with help of php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly something you can do as long as you have a system which can build the sources. I suggest you look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Of course, use `exec` to run these utilities: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: What all things is required to install on my server for this can i run it on a shared hosting or need a vps with root access ?

Comment: Java, if it isn't installed already, along with the Android developers kit: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html Eclipse isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

xampp for android test this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRpLnNlcnZlcndlYiJd

Comment: Hmmm okay, i'm sorry, i just search in google to key web server in android, and then i get this link, i new in stackoverflow. BTW thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice forum to start with http://phpforandroid.net/. I tried it its really good.

Comment: I think its some thing to code android  in php , what i need is to combile and build already coded source using php